# Scroll two horizontalPagger in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have two HorizontalPagers where when one scrolls, the other one starts scrolling.But when I scroll one of them, the animation of that one has a problem and lags

```
the animation of the scroll not working correctly:

 val imagePagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 3 })
    val textPagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 3 })
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scrollingFollowingPair by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (imagePagerState.isScrollInProgress) {
                imagePagerState to textPagerState
            } else if (textPagerState.isScrollInProgress) {
                textPagerState to imagePagerState
            } else null
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(scrollingFollowingPair) {
        val (scrollingState, followingState) = scrollingFollowingPair ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        snapshotFlow { scrollingState.currentPage + scrollingState.currentPageOffsetFraction }
            .collect { pagePart ->
                val divideAndRemainder = BigDecimal.valueOf(pagePart.toDouble())
                    .divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.ONE)

                val page = divideAndRemainder[0].toInt()
                val fraction = divideAndRemainder[1].toFloat().coerceIn(-0.5f, 0.5f)

                followingState.animateScrollToPage(page, fraction)
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to combine two flows instead of calculating page and fraction manually. Also `scrollToPage` is better here than `animateScrollToPage`. Try replacing your `snapshotFlow` with this:

```
val fractionFlow = snapshotFlow { scrollingState.currentPageOffsetFraction }
val pageFlow = snapshotFlow { scrollingState.currentPage }
combine(pageFlow, fractionFlow) { page, fraction ->
    followingState.scrollToPage(page, fraction)
}.collect {}
```

Comment: I get this error in some devices: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pageOffsetFraction -0.5013889 is not within the range -0.5 to 0.5" do you know why?

Comment: I don't, [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/PagerState#currentPageOffsetFraction()) clearly states it's supposed to be in -0.5 to 0.5 range. And it's too big for a precision error. @SaeedNoshadi